# Custom report type - added fields via lookup but unable to filter in the report

Tags: custom-report-type

I created a custom report type for order and order product objects. created look up the product family field from the products object. all good. they show up in the new report. but filtering by product family does not return the desired result (specific product family value). is a filter not possible on a lookup field in custom report types? remove the filter and all values for the product family show up fine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: which is the target object in the CRT - the Order or the Order Product?

Comment: order products is the target object. look up is for products object.

Comment: In a report based on the CRT, can the filters ONLY be the fields from the target object and NOT from the lookup fields in CRT?